# Does || have any special meaning in css comments?

Tags: css

I was going through mozilla web-dev tutorial and noticed that there are `||` signs in every css comment. The stylesheet looks like this:

```
/* || General setup */

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
  background-color: #a9a9a9;
}

body {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* || typography */
```

Is there any special meaning to the `||` ?

Comment: Nothing has special meaning with a comment, the || are a deliberate aid to searching, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Contribute/Guidelines/Code_samples

Comment: More specifically https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Contribute/Guidelines/Code_samples#Use_CSS_flags

Answer (score 2):

no there isn't any meaning to that in CSS comments